# Was bedeutet "auf dem Schlauch stehen"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

Was genau bedeutet „auf dem Schlauch stehen“?
Ist es so etwas wie „ich bin nicht interessiert“ oder „ich verstehe nichts“?

Über eine Antwort bin ich dankbar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Redewendung *"auf dem Schlauch stehen"* bedeutet, dass jemand in einer gewissen Situation etwas auch nach längerem Überlegen nicht versteht und deshalb nicht weiter kommt in der Angelegenheit.

Man kann es sich bildlich so vorstellen: Eine Person steht — ohne es zu bemerken — auf dem eigenen Wasserschlauch und kann nicht verstehen, dass kein Wasser rauskommt.

Man hört die Aussage häufig von den betroffenen Personen selbst, die damit die eigene Hilflosigkeit ausdrücken. Wenn andere Leute die Person beschreiben wollten, könnten sie die Wendungen

- begriffsstutzig sein
- ein Brett vor dem Kopf haben
- eine lange Leitung haben
- schwer von Begriff sein

verwenden. Es ist aber zu beachten, dass die Ausdrücke unter Umständen beleidigend wirken können.

Comment: Die Redewendung wird ausserdem insbesondere dann verwendet wenn die Loesung relativ einfach, oder zumindest vom Schlauchsteher nachvollziehbar ist. Man wuerde nicht in einem Zusammenhang wie "Ich versteh Quantenphysik nicht" sagen dass man auf dem Schlauch steht.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, whenever *I stand on my [hose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hose)*, I am inhibited from finishing my watering my garden.  Pragmatically **stehe ich aufm Schlauch**, whenever a missing puzzle piece of knowledge or missing device is preventing me from finishing my task.